Building new kernel, need help
Someone on Reddit showed me this yesterday
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/westeri/thunderbolt.git/commit/?h=next&id=9a966517a83090ee3e26e9a93a92523e2358c5b3
Looks like I should be able to change one line of code, and then I can achieve what I want, but this is going to require rebuilding the kernel
I haven't built a custom kernel in a long long time, and never on a deb based distro
I am following these instructions here
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
I used apt and downloaded the kernel, changed the thunderbolt file and added the line of code
I get to “quicker build” fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
And the build fails, the error is
Debug: /home/nick/linux-oem-6.5-6.5.0/debian/stamps/stamp-install-generic kernel_file arch/x86/boot/bzImage kernfile arch/x86/boot/bzImage install_file vmlinuz instfile vmlinuz
dh_testdir
dh_prep -plinux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-1019-generic
dh_prep: error: Requested unknown package linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-1019-generic via -p/--package, expected one of: linux-oem-6.5-headers-6.5.0-1019 linux-oem-6.5-tools-6.5.0-1019 linux-oem-6.5-tools-host linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-modules-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-headers-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-oem-6.5-lib-rust-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-image-unsigned-6.5.0-1019-oem-dbgsym linux-tools-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-cloud-tools-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-buildinfo-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-modules-ipu6-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-modules-ivsc-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-modules-iwlwifi-6.5.0-1019-oem linux-modules-usbio-6.5.0-1019-oem
dh_prep: error: unknown option or error during option parsing; aborting
make: *** [debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:132: /home/nick/linux-oem-6.5-6.5.0/debian/stamps/stamp-install-generic] Error 255

If there's an easier way to achieve this, or if someone could help me with this, I would appreciate it.

I would consider this out of scope of askubuntu even if you use an Ubuntu kernel. As users of Ubuntu we really do not create own kernels so I would assume the expers on this would be at U+L and as such I would have asked this on U+L ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ) myself.

So, I tried doing the exact same instructions but with a different kernel version, and now everything works…not sure what the problem was, but I am good to go.  I was able to boot the modded kernel.  My modification works!  I don’t have WiFi but I can fix that easily.

I figured it out.  The wiki instructs to use the “binary-generic” argument but I was trying to build the OEM kernel.  Changed to “binary-oem” and it works.  Older one was a -generic kernel that’s why that one worked.
